# xslt cascading structure should generate multi files and catalogue (result-document?)

Tags: file, xslt, split, parallel-processing, cascading

I got a structure like this:

```
<chapter 1>
    .. some infos of Chapter 1
    <Chapter 1.1>
        .. some infos of Chapter 1.1
        <Chapter 1.1.1>
         ... rekursiv going down here


       .. some infos of Chapter 1.1
    </Chapter 1.1>
    <Chapter 1.2>
        .. some infos of Chapter 1.2
        <Chapter 1.2.1>
         ... rekursiv going down here


       .. some infos of Chapter 1.2
    </Chapter 1.2>

    .. some infos of Chapter 1
</Chapter 1>
```

should result in following files:
chapter_1.xml
chapter_1.1.xml
chapter 1.1.1.xml
chapter 1.2.xml
chapter 1.2.1.xml

and(!) a contentfile showing the structure of files.

a) I guess xsl:result-document would work to generate all the chapterFiles while going recursively the structure.

b) to generate the contentfile it would need a document (some sort of file handler) open all the time to write the content in parallel
OR
a second loop over the structure just fpr the content

Would you please give me your opinion/best way how to handle a) and b)

Answer (score 1):

This all falls out naturally with a structure like this:

```
<xsl:template match="Chapter">
  <!-- add a link from the containing chapter to the contained chapter -->
  <link href="Chapter{@id}">Chapter {title}</link>
  <!-- process the contained chapter -->
  <xsl:result-document href="Chapter{@id}">
     <article>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
     </article>
  </xsl:result-document>
</xsl:template>
```

In other words, at any "time" in your processing (though it's best to avoid temporal language when describing a functional program) there's a stack of open result documents corresponding to the stack of chapter elements in the input, and new elements are added to the result document that's on the top of this stack.

Saxon-EE will in fact write multiple result documents in parallel (in separate threads) but that's not something you need to be aware of.

See the play.xsl sample stylesheet in the saxon-resources download at saxonica.com for an example of this - it's not recursive, it has a fixed three levels of play/act/scene, but the principle is the same.